# Use environment variable to set `include_directories`

Tags: cmake, environment-variables, include-path

I have an environment variable that contains paths to manually 'installed' header only libraries:

```
export INCLUDE_PATH="/some/path":"${INCLUDE_PATH}"
```

I want to use this in my `CMakeLists.txt`. But when I do:

```
include_directories("$ENV{INCLUDE_PATH}")
```

the paths appear not be properly added (no CMake error, but the compiler does not know where to look).

Comment: include_directories don't have a ":" so CMake really don't know how to look there.

Comment: The problem isn't with environment variables, the problem is with value you have passed to `include_directories`. In CMake, strings in the *list* are separated with semicolon (`;`) , not with `:`. Correct:  `export INCLUDE_PATH="/some/path;${INCLUDE_PATH}"`. Also, when you pass a list of parameters to the function, do not enclose this list with double quotes. Otherwise CMake joins all strings in the list into single parameter.

Comment: @Tsyvarev That makes a lot of sense. Along these lines the answer is the solution, provided that the 'bugs' you pointed out are fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to replace the `':'` char to `';'`. The `';'` is the way CMake deals with lists.

```
string(REPLACE ":" ";" INCLUDE_LIST $ENV{INCLUDE_PATH})

include_directories(${INCLUDE_LIST})
```

Comment: You forget to dereference variable in `include_directories` call. Also, instead of creating intermediate `INCLUDE_PATH` variable, value of the environment variable can be passed directly to `string(REPLACE)`.

Comment: Thanks, that works. You can maybe integrate the explanation of @Tsyvarev and fix the 'bugs' that he pointed out, to make this into the answer?